# R Corrplot: italicize Y-axis labels

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I have a problem that would be extremely easy to solve in `ggplot`, but can´t figure out how to make it work in `corrplot`. How to make y-axis labels in italics??

```
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method="circle")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `font = 3` it will italicize all the axes. If you only want the Y axis, a workaround is:

```
par(mar = c(4, 6, 4, 4))
temp <- corrplot(M, method = "circle", font = 3, tl.pos='n',
                 mar = c(0, 0, 4, 0))
mtext(unique(temp$corrPos$yName), 
      at = unique(temp$corrPos$y), side = 2, las = 1,
      font = 3)
mtext(unique(temp$corrPos$xName), 
      at = unique(temp$corrPos$x), las = 2)
```

Output:
[image]

Though may need some tweaking of the margins on your end to line things up.

Answer (score 2):

In `corrplot`, there is a `...` argument which allows extra parameters to be passed to the base R `text` function. Since `text` has a `font` parameter, where the value 3 means italics, you can do:

```r
library(corrplot)
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, method="circle", font = 3)
```

[image]